# cleveref conflicts with polyglossia when required in a class

Tags: document-classes, polyglossia, cleveref, documentclass-writing, debugging

When I run the following MWE (with `xelatex`):

```
% File myclass.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}

% File main.tex
\documentclass{myclass}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
bla
\end{document}
```

I get these errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Command \crefrangeconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefrangepreconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefrangepostconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefpairconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefmiddleconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \creflastconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefpairgroupconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \crefmiddlegroupconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
Command \creflastgroupconjunction undefined. \begin{document}
```

This is *not* the case when `cleveref` is loaded with `\usepackage{}` at the beginning of `main.tex`. Has anyone an explanation why this happens?

Comment: cleveref expects that the language is set before it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ulrike-fischer, the problem is that `cleveref` doesn't know which language to use. According to the docs, the best solution should be

```
\documentclass[english]{myclass}
```

if I don't want to specify the language directly in `myclass.cls`.